# Read Strings in Python

Tags: python, string

I have some values in a string

```
[AD6:0.02] [AD7:0.03] [AD8:0.19][AD3:6][AD0:22][AD1:22][AD4:48.00][AD5:0.01] [AD6:0.03]
```

I just want to read the values of each 'AD' like 0.02 in AD6 for example. The string changes each time, so I cannot use 'substring'.

Here is my code

```
while True:

    data = ser.read(9999)

    for x in data:
        if ((x==':') & (x+1=='0')):
            print 'Achou'
```

Does someone have an idea about how I can extract the value of each AD and put it in a variable ? (The is in a loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.findall()` with a proper regex:

```
In [80]: s = "[AD6:0.02] [AD7:0.03] [AD8:0.19][AD3:6][AD0:22][AD1:22][AD4:48.00][AD5:0.01] [AD6:0.03]"

In [81]: regex = re.compile(r'AD\d:([\d.]+)')

In [82]: regex.findall(s)
Out[82]: ['0.02', '0.03', '0.19', '6', '22', '22', '48.00', '0.01', '0.03']
```

If you want to convert the values to float you better to use `finditer()` that returns an iterator-like object and convert the matched groups to float using `float()` within a list comprehension:

```
In [85]: [float(x.group(1)) for x in regex.finditer(s)]
Out[85]: [0.02, 0.03, 0.19, 6.0, 22.0, 22.0, 48.0, 0.01, 0.03]
```

But note that this might raise a `ValueError` if your number are not valid digits. In that case you better to use a regular loop and handle the exceptions with a `try-except` expression.

Comment: good, but this values are not Static, being more clear, this is temperature and humidity you know ? do you think that will work ?

Comment: @FelipeFerreiraMendes Why does that matter? If your string is in the format you have given, then this answer shows how to extract the values you asked for

Comment: Though, seeing `{'AD6': 0.02}` might be a better answer

Comment: Everything is explained in the answer. You have a variable called `data` which contains the data. Here we have `s`. If you are not able to transfer this solution to your program you really should work through the tutorial again.